# BlackBerry 7: Odd Memory Leak in Root Process

Tags: java, blackberry, memory-leaks, persistence

I'm now investigating a memory leak in a legacy BB7 app, originally developed for OS 4.5 by devs that are no longer in the company. The hole is so big the device degrades with time and puts the device in a sluggish state in a few hours of use. It gets slower because the dreaded black clock appears in screen with an increasing frequency for simple operations. I've confirmed with the debugger that the black clock appears when the Garbage Collector fires in, and no other heavy processing is taking place during these intervals. Apparently these automatic GC operations do not aleviate the memory shortage.

I've inspected the process app memory using the BlackBerry Objects View in BB plugin for eclipse. I've not seen an abnormal number of instances of any kind inside this process. Interestingly, a great number of instances of a class from the model appear to live in the root process RAM (pid=0) despite being created by this app process. And they appear to be leaked due to iterations over the persistent vector that holds them (for example: there are only 100 instances in persistent store, but after a few iterations over the persistent vector, there are 2000 instances in the root process RAM. Clearly the 1900 extra instances are clones of the ones already in persistence).
With the debugger on, I can see that the instances keep piling in RAM and are not collected by the brief automatic GC that I can see in the console, but they are removed when I manually force the GC from the debugger (which takes considerably longer to run).

The main suspect is a DAO class that is kept in the `RuntimeStore` as a singleton instance (must be called from alternate entry points too). It holds a reference to a `BigVector` that is saved in the `PersistentStore`, and contains instances of the model class above mentioned. This is a shortened version:

```
    public class LeakyDAO { 
        private long persistentStoreId;
        private long runtimeStoreId;
        private PersistentObject persistentObject;
        private BigVector bigVector;

        private LeakyDAO(long id_p, long id_r) {
            persistentStoreId = id_p;
            runtimeStoreId = id_r;
            persistentObject = PersistentStore.getPersistentObject(persistentStoreId);
            Object o = persistentObject.getContents();      

            if(o instanceof BigVector){
                bigVector = (BigVector) o;
            } else {
                bigVector = new BigVector();
                persistentObject.setContents(bigVector);
            }       
        }

        public static synchronized LeakyDAO getInstance(long idPersist, long idRuntime) {
            RuntimeStore rs = RuntimeStore.getRuntimeStore();
            LeakyDAO dao = (LeakyDAO) rs.get(idRuntime);
            if (dao == null) {
                dao = new LeakyDAO(idPersist, idRuntime);
                try {
                    rs.put(idRuntime, dao);
                } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                    //Already exists
                }
            }
            return dao;
        }

        public synchronized Object get(int index) {
            return ObjectGroup.expandGroup(bigVector.elementAt(index));
        }


        public synchronized void insertAt(int index, Persistable p) {       
            ObjectGroup.createGroupIgnoreTooBig(p);
            if (index >= bigVector.size()) {
                bigVector.addElement(p);
            } else {
                bigVector.insertElementAt(p, index);
            }
            persistentObject.setContents(bigVector);
            persistentObject.commit();
        }   
    }
```

Is there anything horribly wrong about this class I'm overlooking? At this point I can't yet confirm these instances are actually the cause of the problem because the app behaves quite diferently when plugged to the debugger. But could it be possible that, due to a bug in the OS (or known behaviour) some instances are being leaked after calling repeatedly `get` or `insertAt`?

---

UPDATE
The problems with automatic garbage collection and some OutOfMemoryErrors are only observed when the debugger is on. When it is not in debug mode, the automatic GC does work as expected, so I think there's a problem with the debugger. I've also had a few resets when in the objects view.

Answer (score 1):

I see every 'get' calls expandGroup, and every insert calls createGroup.  I don't think these functions make any attempt at being efficient.  Meaning they copy the objects each time, even if it isn't necessary.

Is the code that uses these objects modifying them?  Or, if there is modification, can you narrow that down, and make just those cases use a 'getMutable' ?
If you can do either of those, you'll be able to remove 'createGroup' from the insertAt function, and remove 'expandGroup' from the get function, and save on the object copies.